# FileNotFoundError while trying to run a C++ code using Python

Tags: python, c++

I'm new to C++ and I want to run this C++ code using python.

The C++ code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello this is inside c++ ");
    return 0;
}
```

The Python Code

```
import subprocess

print("in python file")
subprocess.call(["gcc", "c_file.cpp"])
subprocess.call("./a.out")
print("task is done")
```

The error I'm getting when I run using the python file

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amiru Randil\PycharmProjects\pythonRunC++Code\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["gcc", "c_file.c"])
  File "C:\Python382\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Python382\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python382\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: changed it but still getting the same error

Comment: you need to put the full path to gcc ... you can find this with `where gcc` when you run it from cmd.exe

Comment: Still not working. Getting the same error

Comment: a. out is the default executable name generated by the gcc. So it's not a file, it's a command to run the C++ file

Comment: Oh I see, could you try `subprocess.call(["./a.out"])` instead of `subprocess.call("./a.out")`? Does it work?

Comment: Still not working. Getting the same error

Comment: Is the file c_file.cpp in same directory as the Python script or is it on a parent or subdirectory?

Comment: I highly advise against using Python as a build system. Probably the most versatile and well used build system is CMake, which can be configured for pretty much everything under the sun. It takes a bit to learn to use properly, but it's so powerful.

Comment: it's in the same directory

Comment: Is the command `gcc c_file.cpp` works on your terminal? Does it create a "a.out" or "a.exe" file in your local directory after executing?

Comment: it compiles when I run it on the terminal

Comment: Could you try changing the subprocess call `subprocess.call(["gcc", "c_file.cpp"])` to `subprocess.call(["gcc", "C:\Users\Amiru Randil\PycharmProjects\pythonRunC++Code\c_file.cpp"])`? Does it create a "a.exe" or "a.out" file or does it output a different error message?

Comment: `import subprocess

print("in python file")
subprocess.call(["gcc", "c_file.cpp"])
subprocess.call(["a.exe"])
print("task is done")`

Comment: this code worked

Comment: thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

Can you compile and run the cpp file standalone? That is, are you able to run it normally? Because I do not see any error in your code apart from thinking that you have not installed the c++ compiler.

Here is my c_file.cpp:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello this is inside c++\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my run_c.py:

```py
import subprocess

print("in python file")
subprocess.call(["g++", "c_file.cpp"])
subprocess.call("./a.out")
print("task is done")
```

When I run it, I get the correct output printed. Like so:python run_c.py

```
in python file
hello this is inside c++
task is done
```

Answer (score 1):

As your error shows you are in windows so the executable
will not be called a.out it will be a.exe also ./ is not used in windows.

```
import subprocess

print("in python file")
subprocess.call(["gcc", "c_file.cpp"])
# change ./a.out to a.exe
subprocess.call("a.exe")
print("task is done")
```

Comment: Also, an automated Python script is not what should be used as a build system. CMake is the most prominent build system for a reason